# Unique url htaccess or other redirect needed

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I need to somehow make  one unique url redirect.

For instance:
http://www.mydomain.com**/shop** needs to redirect back to http://www.mydomain.com

BUT

http://www.mydomain.com/shop/tshirts etc still needs to function, I cant manage to get this to work. No matter what I attempt anything containing /shop/*xxx* redirects which I dont want it to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Write this in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /shop
Rewriterule ^$ http://mydomain.com/test/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: this has seemed to work I will wait a bit before marking it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable MOD_REWRITE.

Place a `.htaccess` file in the root folder of your server and have it contain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)shop/$ http://mydomain.com/ [R,L]
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Your redirection seems simple enough, so you can use redirect directive for this.

In your .htaccess file, add this redirect.

```
Redirect 301 /shop  http://www.mydomain.com/


    301: permanent
    302: temp
    303: seeother
    410: gone
```

mod_alias needs to be enabled in config.